# Getting parent element with data attribute not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to build a modal using contents of a "row" of elements. This could be a `table` or a group of `div`, so I cannot be specific with my JS:

My HTML is:

```
<div class="row" data-uuid='abc123'>
   ... more elements ...
   <div class='project-description'>blah blah</div>
   ... more elements ...
       <a href="#" class='btn' data-delete-uuid='abc123' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete">
```

The HTML could also be:

```
<table class="mytable">
<tbody>
   ... more rows and cells ...
   <tr data-uuid='abc123'>
       <td class='project-decription'>blah blah</td>
       <td>
           <a href="#" class='btn' data-delete-uuid='abc123' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete">
       </td>
```

In my JS I am trying to find the "parent" or "closest" element with `data-uuid` matching the uuid I get from the clicked element `data-delete-uuid` in html with differing structures per above.

```
$('#delete').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

    var uuid = $(event.relatedTarget).attr('data-delete-uuid');

    var rowDelete = $(event.relatedTarget).closest('[data-uuid="' + uuid + '"]');

    console.log(rowDelete.find('.project-description').html()); <-- UNDEFINED
});
```

At all times the page will contain two elements with `data-uuid="abc123"`, if this makes any difference. I am trying to find the closest up the DOM from the button pressed.

What have I missed? Should this not work?

Comment: In the HTML you show, there is no element with `id="delete"`, but assuming that event handler works somehow and the `event.relatedTarget` element is the anchor element, your code should work for the HTML with the DIV; the HTML with the table doesn't have any elements with `data-uuid`...

Comment: Hi @nnnnnn sorry, I missed some html as part of my question. The `#delete` element is a bootstrap 3 modal.

Comment: Maybe try `console.log(uuid)` to confirm that that first line in the event handler works as expected? (By the way, your edited HTML is invalid: you've got a TD nested inside a TD.)

Comment: @nnnnnn yes uuid is getting picked up ok

Comment: There's a typo in your class name in the table: you have left the "s" out of `project-description`. If you fix that it all works: https://jsfiddle.net/4rq25ymv/1/

Answer (score 2):

You may not need jQuery.

This simple javascript will jump up a parentNode, look for what you're after from the parent, and if not found, keep jumping up to the root of the DOM.

```
/**
 * @param {HTMLElement} entry
 * @param {string} selector
 * @return {HTMLElement | null}
 */ 
function closest(entry, selector) {
  var parent = entry;
  var element = null;

  while (parent && !element) {
    element = parent.querySelector(selector);
    parent = parent.parentNode;
  }
  return element;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You may need to use `event.currentTarget` or `event.target` because `event.relatedTarget` may be undefined for the `show.bs.modal` event. See the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/event.relatedTarget/) where it specifies info only about the `mouseout` and `mouseover` events.